# How to explode multiple columns of a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which consists lists in columns similar to the following. The length of the lists in all columns is not same.

```
Name  Age  Subjects                  Grades
[Bob] [16] [Maths,Physics,Chemistry] [A,B,C]
```

I want to explode the dataframe in such a way that i get the following output-

```
Name Age Subjects Grades
Bob  16   Maths     A
Bob  16  Physics    B
Bob  16  Chemistry  C
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to match the index in a given array with other arrays in the row? Like how `Maths -> A`, `Physics -> B`, and `Chemistry -> C`. So something like `Maths -> B` would be wrong.

Comment: Yes @Tanjin that would be wrong

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = sql.createDataFrame(
    [(['Bob'], [16], ['Maths','Physics','Chemistry'], ['A','B','C'])],
    ['Name','Age','Subjects', 'Grades'])
df.show()

+-----+----+--------------------+---------+
| Name| Age|            Subjects|   Grades|
+-----+----+--------------------+---------+
|[Bob]|[16]|[Maths, Physics, ...|[A, B, C]|
+-----+----+--------------------+---------+
```

Use `udf` with `zip`. Those columns needed to `explode` have to be merged before exploding.

```
combine = F.udf(lambda x, y: list(zip(x, y)),
              ArrayType(StructType([StructField("subs", StringType()),
                                    StructField("grades", StringType())])))

df = df.withColumn("new", combine("Subjects", "Grades"))\
       .withColumn("new", F.explode("new"))\
       .select("Name", "Age", F.col("new.subs").alias("Subjects"), F.col("new.grades").alias("Grades"))
df.show()


+-----+----+---------+------+
| Name| Age| Subjects|Grades|
+-----+----+---------+------+
|[Bob]|[16]|    Maths|     A|
|[Bob]|[16]|  Physics|     B|
|[Bob]|[16]|Chemistry|     C|
+-----+----+---------+------+
```

Comment: what should I do if I need to put A B and C in different columns rather than rows

Comment: UDFs are not the efficient and performant. They should be avoided if a pyspark API solution exists.

Answer (score 71):

PySpark has added an `arrays_zip` function in 2.4, which eliminates the need for a Python UDF to zip the arrays.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = sql.createDataFrame(
    [(['Bob'], [16], ['Maths','Physics','Chemistry'], ['A','B','C'])],
    ['Name','Age','Subjects', 'Grades'])
df = df.withColumn("new", F.arrays_zip("Subjects", "Grades"))\
       .withColumn("new", F.explode("new"))\
       .select("Name", "Age", F.col("new.Subjects").alias("Subjects"), F.col("new.Grades").alias("Grades"))
df.show()

+-----+----+---------+------+
| Name| Age| Subjects|Grades|
+-----+----+---------+------+
|[Bob]|[16]|    Maths|     A|
|[Bob]|[16]|  Physics|     B|
|[Bob]|[16]|Chemistry|     C|
+-----+----+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 14):

**Arriving late to the party :-)**

The simplest way to go is by using [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) that doesn't have python API but is supported by `selectExpr`.

```
df.selectExpr('Name[0] as Name','Age[0] as Age','inline(arrays_zip(Subjects,Grades))').show()
```

---

```
+----+---+---------+------+
|Name|Age| Subjects|Grades|
+----+---+---------+------+
| Bob| 16|    Maths|     A|
| Bob| 16|  Physics|     B|
| Bob| 16|Chemistry|     C|
+----+---+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
df.select(explode(split(col("Subjects"))).alias("Subjects")).show()
```

you can convert the data frame to an RDD.

For an RDD you can use a `flatMap` function to separate the Subjects.

Comment: I've tried using a flat map as df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: zip(*[x[c] for c in dcols])).toDF(dcols) but it is only giving me the first row and ignoring the remaining rows-  |16 |A     |Bob |Maths   |

Answer (score 1):

I've used the very elegant solution from @Nasty but if you have a lot of columns to explode, the scheduler on server side might run into issues if you generate lots of new dataframes with "withColumn()". So I slightly adapted the code to run more efficient and is more convenient to use:

```
def explode_all(df: DataFrame, index=True, cols: list = []):
"""Explode multiple array type columns.
loop through explodable signals [array type columns] and explode multiple columns.
First, colums need to be zipped into the df:
[a, [1, 2, 3]], [b, [10, 20, 30]] -> [[[a, 1], [b, 10]], [[a, 2], [b, 20]], [[a, 3], [b, 30]]]
In a for loop the zipped df is passed into separate columns#

df -- Required: Input dataframe

index -- Optional: if an index is required (default: True)

cols -- Optional: list of column names.
"""

if not isinstance(df, DataFrame):           # Error handling
    raise TypeError("Input data must be a PySpark DataFrame")

if cols:
    expl_cols = [col for col, col_type in df.dtypes if (col_type[:5] == 'array' and col in cols)]
else:
    expl_cols = [col for col, col_type in df.dtypes if col_type[:5] == 'array']

if len(expl_cols) == 0:                     # Error handling
    raise ValueError("Input data does not contain any array columns")

if index:
    df = df.select("*", F.posexplode(F.arrays_zip(*expl_cols)).alias("signal_index", "exp_combo")).drop(*expl_cols)
else:
    df = df.select("*", F.explode(F.arrays_zip(*expl_cols)).alias("exp_combo")).drop(*expl_cols)

df = df.select("*", *[F.column('exp_combo.' + name).alias(name) for name in expl_cols]).drop(F.col('exp_combo'))

return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste function if you need to repeat this quickly and easily across a large number of columns in a dataset

```
cols = ["word", "stem", "pos", "ner"]

def explode_cols(self, data, cols):
    data = data.withColumn('exp_combo', f.arrays_zip(*cols))
    data = data.withColumn('exp_combo', f.explode('exp_combo'))
    for col in cols:
        data = data.withColumn(col, f.col('exp_combo.' + col))

    return data.drop(f.col('exp_combo'))

result = explode_cols(data, cols)
```

Your welcome :)

Comment: arrays_zip does not take list as input

Comment: @Quynh-MaiChu you need to use a starred expression as written in the function above f.arrays_zip(*cols).. so that python will process your list as arguments instead of a list object. you can also do ..._zip(f.col('col1'), f.col('col2')) if you find that clearer

Answer (score 0):

When Exploding multiple columns, the above solution comes in handy only when the length of array is same, but if they are not.
It is better to explode them separately and take distinct values each time.

```
df = sql.createDataFrame(
    [(['Bob'], [16], ['Maths','Physics','Chemistry'], ['A','B','C'])],
    ['Name','Age','Subjects', 'Grades'])

df = df.withColumn('Subjects',F.explode('Subjects')).select('Name','Age','Subjects', 'Grades').distinct()

df = df.withColumn('Grades',F.explode('Grades')).select('Name','Age','Subjects', 'Grades').distinct()

df.show()

 +----+---+---------+------+
|Name|Age| Subjects|Grades|
+----+---+---------+------+
| Bob| 16|    Maths|     A|
| Bob| 16|  Physics|     B|
| Bob| 16|Chemistry|     C|
+----+---+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nasty for saving the day.
Just small tweaks to get the code working.

```
def explode_cols( df, cl):
df = df.withColumn('exp_combo', arrays_zip(*cl))
df = df.withColumn('exp_combo', explode('exp_combo'))
for colm in cl:
    final_col = 'exp_combo.'+ colm 
    df = df.withColumn(final_col, col(final_col))
    
    #print col
    #print ('exp_combo.'+ colm)
return df.drop(col('exp_combo'))
```