# Explode two PySpark arrays and keep elements from same positions

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe (say `df1`) which has the following columns

1.> `category` : some string
2.> `array1` : an array of elements
3.> `array2` : an array of elements

Following is an example of `df1`

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+
|category|        array1|        array2|
+--------+--------------+--------------+
|A       |  [x1, x2, x3]|  [y1, y2, y3]|
|B       |      [u1, u2]|      [v1, v2]|
+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

For each row, the length of `array1` is equal to the length of `array2`.  In each column, I expect different rows to have different sizes of arrays for `array1` (and `array2`).

**I want to form separate columns (say `element1` and `element2`) such that in each row, the columns `element1` and `element2` contain elements from same locations of `array1` and `array2` respectively.**

Following is an example of the output dataframe (say `df2`) that I want:

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|category|        array1|        array2|  element1|  element2|
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|A       |  [x1, x2, x3]|  [y1, y2, y3]|        x1|        y1|
|A       |  [x1, x2, x3]|  [y1, y2, y3]|        x2|        y2|
|A       |  [x1, x2, x3]|  [y1, y2, y3]|        x3|        y3|
|B       |      [u1, u2]|      [v1, v2]|        u1|        v1|
|B       |      [u1, u2]|      [v1, v2]|        u2|        v2|
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Below is what I have tried till now (but it gives me values in `element1` and `element2` from different positions in addition to what I want.)

```
df2 = df1.select( "*", F.explode("array1").alias("element1") ).select( "*", F.explode("array2").alias("element2") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spark >=2.4 you could use [Higher-Order Functions](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html):

```
data = [('A', ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']),
        ('B', ['u1', 'u2'], ['v1', 'v2'])
      ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["category", "array1", "array2"])

# tranform array1, array2 => [struct(element1, element2)]
transform_expr = "transform(array1, (x, i) -> struct(x as element1, array2[i] as element2))"

# explode transformed arrays and extract values of element1 and element2
df.withColumn("merged_arrays", explode(expr(transform_expr))) \
    .withColumn("element1", col("merged_arrays.element1")) \
    .withColumn("element2", col("merged_arrays.element2")) \
    .drop("merged_arrays") \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+--------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
|category|array1      |array2      |element1|element2|
+--------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
|A       |[x1, x2, x3]|[y1, y2, y3]|x1      |y1      |
|A       |[x1, x2, x3]|[y1, y2, y3]|x2      |y2      |
|A       |[x1, x2, x3]|[y1, y2, y3]|x3      |y3      |
|B       |[u1, u2]    |[v1, v2]    |u1      |v1      |
|B       |[u1, u2]    |[v1, v2]    |u2      |v2      |
+--------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

**Explanation for `transform` function:**

The function takes the first array `array1` and applies a lambda function `(x, i) -> struct(string, string)`, where `x` the actual value and `i` its index in the array. For each value, we return a struct containing that value as `element1` and the corresponding value in `array2` (using the index `i`) as `element2`.

The rest is just exploding the result of transformation and accessing the struct elements we created.

Answer (score 4):

**Initialization**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

columns = ['category','array1','array2']
vals = [
     ('A', ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['y1','y2','y3']),
     ('B', ['u1', 'u2',], ['v1','v2'])
]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
```

[Based on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57769250/8342978) `arrays_zip` [[docs]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=arrays_zip#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip)in spark >= `2.4`

```py
df.withColumn('new', F.arrays_zip('array1','array2')).withColumn('ex',explode('new'))\
    .select('category','array1','array2',
            col("ex.array1").alias('element1'),
            col("ex.array2").alias('element2')\
           ).drop('new','ex').show()
```

**Output**

```
+--------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
|category|      array1|      array2|element1|element2|
+--------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
|       A|[x1, x2, x3]|[y1, y2, y3]|      x1|      y1|
|       A|[x1, x2, x3]|[y1, y2, y3]|      x2|      y2|
|       A|[x1, x2, x3]|[y1, y2, y3]|      x3|      y3|
|       B|    [u1, u2]|    [v1, v2]|      u1|      v1|
|       B|    [u1, u2]|    [v1, v2]|      u2|      v2|
+--------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

**Explanation**
Looking seeing what `arrays_zip` produces basically explains everything. We lump/zip the cols together with it and then `explode` it. Then simply reference the corresponding structs within the new column created by explode.

```
>>> df.withColumn('new', F.arrays_zip('array1','array2')).show(truncate=False)
+--------+------------+------------+------------------------------+
|category|array1      |array2      |new                           |
+--------+------------+------------+------------------------------+
|A       |[x1, x2, x3]|[y1, y2, y3]|[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]]|
|B       |[u1, u2]    |[v1, v2]    |[[u1, v1], [u2, v2]]          |
+--------+------------+------------+------------------------------+
```