# Split & Map fields of array<string> in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe as below with 7 columns out of which 6 fields are array and one column is array<array>.

Sample data is as below

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|customer_id                                                                                                       |equipment_id                                                                                                       |type              |language            |country            |lang_cnt_str                                                                                                                              |model_num                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|[18e644bb-4342-4c22-ab9b-a90fda50ad69, 70f0b998-3e4e-422d-b863-1f5f455c4883, 54a99992-5403-4946-b059-f71ec7ef2cca]|[1407c4a9-b075-4837-bada-690da10717cd, fc4632f3-302b-43cb-9245-ede2d1ac590f, 1407c4a9-b075-4837-bada-690da10717cd]|[comm, comm, vspec]|[cs, en-GB, pt-PT]  |[[CZ], [PT], [PT]] |[(language = 'cs' AND country IS IN ('CZ')), (language = 'en-GB' AND country IS IN ('PT')), (language = 'pt-PT' AND country IS IN ('PT'))]|[1618832612617, 1618832612858, 1618832614027]|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

I want to split and map every element of all columns. Below is the expected output.

```
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|customer_id                            |equipment_id                           |type   |language   |country     |lang_cnt_str                                      |model_num          |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|18e644bb-4342-4c22-ab9b-a90fda50ad69   |1407c4a9-b075-4837-bada-690da10717cd   |comm   |cs         |[CZ]        |(language = 'cs' AND country IS IN ('CZ'))        |1618832612617      |
|70f0b998-3e4e-422d-b863-1f5f455c4883   |fc4632f3-302b-43cb-9245-ede2d1ac590f   |comm   |en-GB      |[PT]        |(language = 'en-GB' AND country IS IN ('PT'))     |1618832612858      |
|54a99992-5403-4946-b059-f71ec7ef2cca   |1407c4a9-b075-4837-bada-690da10717cd   |vspec  |pt-PT      |[PT]        |(language = 'pt-PT' AND country IS IN ('PT'))     |1618832614027      |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

How can we achieve this in pyspark. Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explode multiple columns of a dataframe in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082758/how-to-explode-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)

Comment: Hi @ARCrow Thanks for the response. Its not exactly the same because I have a column country Which is array<array<string>> and I wanna array<string> in the resultant mapping each array<string> to each of the customer_id Column. That's where I'm blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We exchanged a couple of comments above, and I think there's nothing special about the array(array(string)) column. So I post this answer to show the solution posted in [How to explode multiple columns of a dataframe in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082758/how-to-explode-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (['1', '2', '3'], [['1'], ['2'], ['3']])
], ['col1', 'col2'])

df = (df
      .withColumn('zipped', f.arrays_zip(f.col('col1'), f.col('col2')))
      .withColumn('unzipped', f.explode(f.col('zipped')))
      .select(f.col('unzipped.col1'),
              f.col('unzipped.col2')
             )
     )

df.show()
```

The input is:

```
+---------+---------------+
|     col1|           col2|
+---------+---------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[[1], [2], [3]]|
+---------+---------------+
```

And the output is:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1| [1]|
|   2| [2]|
|   3| [3]|
+----+----+
```