# Mapping respective values to respective dates

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Input:**

| Id | FirstDate | LastDate | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-10 | 2023-12-14 | 2,4,6,7,8 |
| 2 | 2024-01-12 | 2023-12-21 | 0,0,16,2,7,0,1,1,2,3 |

**Expected OutPut:**

| Id | FirstDateAndLastDate | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-10 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-12-11 | 4 |
| 1 | 2023-12-12 | 6 |
| 1 | 2023-12-13 | 7 |
| 1 | 2023-12-14 | 8 |
| 2 | 2024-01-12 | 0 |
| 2 | 2024-01-13 | 0 |
| 2 | 2024-01-14 | 16 |
| 2 | 2024-01-15 | 2 |
| 2 | 2024-01-16 | 7 |
| 2 | 2024-01-17 | 0 |
| 2 | 2024-01-18 | 1 |
| 2 | 2024-01-19 | 1 |
| 2 | 2024-01-20 | 2 |
| 2 | 2024-01-21 | 3 |

I am able to get dates as per expected but I am not able to map respective values in front of respective dates.

`df.withColumn("FirstDateAndLastDate", explode(expr("sequence(to_date(FirstDate), to_date(LastDate), interval 1 day)")))`

When I explode it separates the data in rows but not for respective dates.

`df.withColumn("new_value", explode(split(col("values"), ",")))`

Comment: Last date for ID 2 should be 2024-12-21 right? So that each token in the delimited values corresponds to a single day in the interval?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57769250/2956135?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/57769250/2956135 solution worked partially. problem statement is to assign values to respective dates. From this solution I am able to explode values but it is creating duplicate records. Every single date have combination of all values.

Answer (score 0):

Given start_date and end_date are of type datetime.

```
def generate_dates(start_date, end_date, values):
    current_date = start_date
    date_values = []

    while current_date <= end_date:
        date_values.append((current_date, values[len(date_values) % len(values)]))
        current_date += relativedelta.relativedelta(days=1)

    return date_values
```